# How to lock in a single skeleton

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

I'm creating an application using the SDK, in which I must have only one user and lock it so if somebody else comes along, even if that person is closer to Kinect, the application keeps tracking the first skeleton it tracked.

From the msdn library I found I could use the Skeletom Stream Class:

Property: AppChoosesSkeletons = Gets or sets a Boolean value that determines whether the application chooses which skeletons to track.

Method: SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons (Int32) = Chooses one skeleton to track. 
Syntax: public void ChooseSkeletons (int trackingId1)

I'm not very good at programming and I'm using C#, I thought of writing something like the code down, but it says that I'm using an Invalid Expression.

```
SkeletonFrame SFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame();
if (SFrame == null) return;

Skeleton[] Skeletons = new Skeleton[SFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
SFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(Skeletons);

int firstSkeleton = Skeletons[0].TrackingId;
sensor.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(int firstSkeleton);

if (firstSkeleton == null)
return;

if (SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked == firstSkeleton.TrackingState)
{
//body...
```

The problem is with the `sensor.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(int firstSkeleton`, it says `int firstSkeleton cannot be used`. 
Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please, tell me, where and when you get that error.

Comment: @Likurg I wrote it in a different way not sure if it'll work or if it is the best way  `Skeleton closestSkeleton = (from s in Skeletons where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked && s.Joints[JointType.Head].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked select s).OrderBy(s => s.TrackingId).FirstOrDefault();`  From the code I posted before, the problem was with  `sensor.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(int firstSkeleton);`  it said that int firstSkeleton could not be used.  I think my logic is not quite right, there's something missing but I'm not sure how to do it.  Thanks for ur answer

Comment: Have you tried using the Skeletons `TrackingID`? Maybe only pay attention to the first one?

Comment: How to use this in Kinect SDk 1.0

Answer (score 3):

```
sensor.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(int firstSkeleton);
```

What do you want to achive with this line ?

Imo if you want to cast firstSkeleton to int write it like this:

```
sensor.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons((int) firstSkeleton);
```

if you don`t want to cast it and just to give and int variable to methid just write:

```
sensor.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(firstSkeleton);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not lock a skeleton, but you can choose the skeleton that you want to track, regardless of its position. It gets complicated when both people leave the Kinect's field of view.

By setting `AppChoosesSkeletons` to true you are able to chose the user that you want to track. To specify the user or users to track, call the `SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons` method and pass the tracking ID of one or two skeletons you want to track (or no parameters if no skeletons are to be tracked).

Something like this:

```
private void ChooseSkeleton()
  {
    if (this.kinect != null && this.kinect.SkeletonStream != null)
        {
        if (!this.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons)
        {
        this.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons = true; // Ensure AppChoosesSkeletons is set
        }

        foreach (Skeleton skeleton in this.skeletonData.Where(s => s.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
        {
        int ID { get.skeleton[1]}//Get ID here
        }

      if (ID = 0)
      {
        this.kinect.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(ID); // Track this skeleton
      }
    }
  }
```